# Open-source command line application to catalog the files of external hard-drives

Tags: open-source, command-line, macos, hard-disk, catalog

I'm looking for a maintained open-source application to catalog the files of many external harddrives from the command line. The app should run on macOS and maybe on Linux too.

I am thinking of the following workflow:

1. When I have one of the external hardisks attached, I index the files on it via a terminal command. This adds the file and directory names of the hard-disk's filesystem to a central catalog (located internally on my machine, *not* on the external drive).
2. Later, when I want to know on which harddrive a file is, I search the central catalog via a terminal command *without having any external drive attached*. The tool tells me then which hard-drive I have to plug to get to the file.

Bonus would be if the application can group multiple partitions of a hard-drive under one name.

Comment: I found [NeoFinder](https://cdfinder.de/) which looks like a great tool for the job. - However it proprietary and a GUI app.